# JQPlot: Plot series and labels from an external source

Tags: ajax, json, jqplot

I am working with JQPlot to generate a chart pulling data from a database, like in the example here http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php.

The chart is working fine, but at the moment the series labels are hard coded. How can I make this chart to display the series labels from the database too, just like the series? I assume I need to make a new call, to a second file containing the label names, but I am not really sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot) {
    var ret = null;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: url,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            ret = data;
        }
    });
   return ret;
};
var jsonurl = "./index.php";
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', jsonurl,{
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    title: 'Annual Balance Summary',
    legend: {show:true, renderer:$.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer},
    seriesDefaults: {lineWidth:4},
    **series:[{label:'Tilikausi 01/2009 - 12/2009'}, {label:'Tilikausi 01/2010 - 12/2010'}, {label:'Tilikausi 01/2011 - 12/2011'}]**, // THIS ARE THE VALUES I WANT TO BRING FROM THE DATABASE
        showMarker:true,
        pointLabels: { show:true },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {pad:1, numberTicks:12, tickInterval: 1, autoscale:true, tickOptions:{formatString:'%d', fontSize:'10pt', fontFamily:'Tahoma', angle:-40, fontWeight:'normal'}}},
        highlighter: {bringSeriesToFront: true}
        });
});
```

The outcoming json array of the index.php, look like this:

```
[[[0,413010.71],[1,431586.96],[2,418659.56],[3,418776.76],[4,409203.91],[5,392167.56],[6,547296.04],[7,529292.86],[8,523009.35],[9,541452.97],[10,535397.58],[11,555497.48],[12,465849.17]],[[0,465849.17],[1,464569.69],[2,468339.1],[3,471005.39],[4,470786.79],[5,472315.46],[6,492847.16],[7,495973.32],[8,520188.21],[9,550497.27],[10,544294.18],[11,559081.4],[12,479558.69]],[[0,479558.69],[1,467694.94],[2,459592.48],[3,476012.25],[4,463623.8],[5,487588.68],[6,445992.44],[7,457935.72],[8,481076.75],[9,498464.53],[10,508681.42],[11,523928.66],[12,548180.15]]]
```

The array for the series labels should be something like this:

```
[["Tilikausi 01\/2009 - 12\/2009"],["Tilikausi 01\/2010 - 12\/2010"],["Tilikausi 01\/2011 - 12\/2011"]] // Array of series labels
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Is there a way that you could put the labels in an array?

Comment: Yes, I have them in one array with json format already, but I am not sure how to call them inside the plot. I could put them in the same file as the series, but how to call the labels variable separately? Or I could save them in a new file, but again, I don't know how to call that new file inside the plot.

Comment: Could you post *exactly* what comes back from `index.php`?

Comment: [[[1,-4308.6],[2,-11725.18],[3,-23253.57],[4,-13090.03],[5,-4957.11],[6,6696.44],[7,1362.71],[8,-9082.79],[9,14463.21],[10,41868.24],[11,22779.56],[12,53768.78]],[[1,12270.04],[2,9970.12],[3,5261.36],[4,763.03000000002],[5,-12524.35],[6,-1696.5],[7,-8661.49],[8,-37932.8],[9,-20398.15],[10,-34028.76],[11,-54570.88],[12,-22761.54]],[[1,352.21000000001],[2,-3802.9],[3,-1460.66],[4,-16506.25],[5,-11104.05],[6,1767.1399999999],[7,-28274.01],[8,-45344.98],[9,-62276.12],[10,-85437.15],[11,-105465.7],[12,-129859.38]]]

Comment: You say you already have the labels on one array, but where does that data come from? Is it a file that exists on the server?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post. The labels are in a similar array, it looks like the one shown in my post. Should I add that label's array in the same index.php? If both arrays are in index.php how can I call only one of them for its corresponding part in the plot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the key to this one is getting the JSON structured correctly that is retrieved by `index.php`.

Currently you are returning this:

```
[[[0,413010.71],[1,431586.96],[2,418659.56],[3,418776.76],[4,409203.91],[5,392167.56],[6,547296.04],[7,529292.86],[8,523009.35],[9,541452.97],[10,535397.58],[11,555497.48],[12,465849.17]],[[0,465849.17],[1,464569.69],[2,468339.1],[3,471005.39],[4,470786.79],[5,472315.46],[6,492847.16],[7,495973.32],[8,520188.21],[9,550497.27],[10,544294.18],[11,559081.4],[12,479558.69]],[[0,479558.69],[1,467694.94],[2,459592.48],[3,476012.25],[4,463623.8],[5,487588.68],[6,445992.44],[7,457935.72],[8,481076.75],[9,498464.53],[10,508681.42],[11,523928.66],[12,548180.15]]]
```

But what you really need is something like this (some elements of `values` omitted for brevity):

```
{
    values: [[[0,413010.71],[1,431586.96],[2,418659.56],[3,418776.76], ... [12,548180.15]]],        
    labels: [["Tilikausi2 01\/2009 - 12\/2009"],["Tilikausi2 01\/2010 - 12\/2010"],["Tilikausi2 01\/2011 - 12\/2011"]]
}
```

The tricky thing is that labels are assigned to a series when the graph is created. This causes a problem because it really means that the Ajax call must happen prior to creating the graph.

Given the Json as structured above, something like this should do the trick:

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var jsonurl = "./index.php";
//Get the data prior to creating the graph.
var plotData = ajaxDataRenderer(jsonurl);

//plotData.values is now passed in to be the actual data the plot is created from.
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', plotData.values, {
    title: 'Annual Balance Summary',
    legend: {show:true, renderer:$.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer},
    seriesDefaults: {lineWidth:4},
    //The series labels can now be supplied.
    series: plotData.labels,
    showMarker:true,
    pointLabels: { show:true },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {pad:1, numberTicks:12, tickInterval: 1, autoscale:true, tickOptions:{formatString:'%d', fontSize:'10pt', fontFamily:'Tahoma', angle:-40, fontWeight:'normal'}}},
        highlighter: {bringSeriesToFront: true}
});
```

**Edit:**

The other thing you will need to do is modify the `labels` array that comes back. We are still using the `ajaxDataRenderer` function, so just after you have received the data you will need to do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.labels.length; i++) {
    data.labels[i] = { label: data.labels[i][0] };
}
```

All this does is create the kind of object literal that jqplot is expecting when you are specifying labels.

**Edit 2:**

If your JSON looks like:

```
[[["Tilikausi 01\/2009 - 12\/2009"],["Tilikausi 01\/2010 - 12\/2010"],
  ["Tilikausi 01\/2011 - 12\/2011"]],[[[1,-4308.6],[2,-11725.18],[3,-23253.57],
    ...,[10,-85437.15],[11,-10‌​5465.7],[12,-129859.38]]]]
```

Then it should still work, but you would need to refer to things differently. Instead of `plotData.values` you would have `plotData[1]`, and instead of `plotData.labels` you would have `plotData[0]`.

Also, the label rearrangement code would instead look like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    data[0][i] = { label: data[0][i][0] };
}
```

Comment: Yes, you got the exact idea of what I need and your suggestion seems logic. When I try to use the `var plotData = ajaxDataRenderer(jsonurl);` it works ok when there is only one of the arrays (labels or seires and without the name of the array). The moment I put both arrays in index.php or if I add the name of the array it can't render the data anymore. Is it because it is expects json format only?

Comment: Your Ajax request is expecting a JSON response, so what `index.php` produces will need to be valid JSON. This is what I was getting at with the restructured JSON. Would you be able to post what you have in `index.php` now that it is returning both arrays?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and now the json returned by `index.php` looks like this (abbreviated): `[[["Tilikausi 01\/2009 - 12\/2009"],["Tilikausi 01\/2010 - 12\/2010"],["Tilikausi 01\/2011 - 12\/2011"]],[[[1,-4308.6],[2,-11725.18],[3,-23253.57],...,[10,-85437.15],[11,-105465.7],[12,-129859.38]]]]` and is being render as one array. I can't push the variables names in that array anymore, should I split it into the 2 corresponding variables, is there other way to do it? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!!! I would really hug your right now :D... I don't even need to say that it worked perfectly. I am so happy!!! THANKS A MILLION.

Comment: I had a similar problem of wanting to change the Y axis label based on the json data (as the units could change), and this answer helped with that as well. great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Read your values in a javascript array and use it to display values in the legend using the following code-snippet:

```
legend:{
    show: true,
    location: 'ne',
    placement: "outside",
    labels: companies
}
```